# Check for duplicates in ListBox

Tags: c#

What I would like to achieve is as following: every time I add a `student` it should check the `ListBox` if there's a duplicate entry inside. If this is the case it should show a `MessageBox` and prevent adding the item to the `ListBox`.

This is my code at the moment:

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Student student = GetStudent();
       Repository.AddStudent(student);
       if (listBoxStudents.Items.Contains(student))
       {
            MessageBox.Show("This student already exists!");
       }
       else
       {
            listBoxStudents.Items.Add(student);
            ClearandFocus();
       }
}
```

I wonder why my code doesn't work correctly, The input comes from several `TextBoxes` in a form that gets added to a `List<Students>` and `ListBox`.

Comment: Hint: what type does the `Contains()` method take as an argument?

Comment: do you have an id you can use?

Comment: `listBoxStudents.Items.Select(s => s.StudentId).Contains(student)`

Answer (score 3):

This is probably happening because you haven't properly overridden the `Equals` method in your `Student` class.  When you don't override `Equals` based on the class data, the default `Equals` method from the `object` class gets run, and that simply compares object references.  So you're comparing two identical but distinct objects, which results in a value of `false` from `object.Equals`, which causes the `Contains` method to return `false`.

Comment: Good to know.  To be a good .NET citizen, make sure you also override `Student.GetHashCode` (which you should do whenever you override `Equals`).